# How to unwrap double optionals in switch statement -- Swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement

xCode 10.2.1, Swift language unspecified (4, 4.2, 5)

I have two double optional bools. I would like to unwrap them in the switch statement as so..

```
func evaluate() -> Bool? {
    let lhs = try? getLhs() // lhs = Bool??; getLhs() returns Bool?
    let rhs = try? getRhs() // rhs = Bool??; getRhs() returns Bool?
    switch (lhs ?? nil, rhs ?? nil) {
    case (nil, nil):
        return nil
    case (nil, rhs):
        return rhs ?? nil
    case (lhs, nil):
        return lhs ?? nil
    default:
        guard case let lhs?? = lhs, case let rhs?? = rhs  else { return nil }
        return lhs || rhs
    }
}
```

This works, but I'm curious why I need to double unwrap the default case?
I was thinking once the lhs and rhs get unwrapped from the switch inputs, the default case would work with a Bool? for lhs and rhs.

Update --

Thanks for answering. Yes, the double optional is overkill, but what I really wanted to understand was why my default was requiring me to unwrap again. I did not completely understand how switch works with optionals. Alexander helped me understand all the iterations and vacawama gave me a clean implementation.

Comment: One things that would make this easier is to replace `try?` with `try` in a `do/catch`.

Comment: @rmaddy But if the try fails, I want it to return nil, not throw an error

Comment: That's what the `catch` is for. Simply `return nil` in the `catch`.

Comment: @rmaddy In the event the lhs fails, I still want to check if rhs exists to return the value for rhs. I don't want to automatically return nil if lhs fails

Comment: `?? nil` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Alexander please elaborate which place the ?? nil doesn't do anything.

Comment: In Xcode 11 `guard case let lhs? = lhs, case let rhs? = rhs` compiles. Might be due to "Enum cases can now be matched against an optional enum without requiring a ‘?ʼ at the end of the pattern."

Comment: I really can't get behind questions that don't provide enough code even to try to compile. No one knows what your `getLhs` and `getRhs` look like or where this code lives or what we are supposed to return.

Comment: @matt I am using xCode 10.2 still. I'm not sure why getLhs and getRhs are relevant. They return Bool?? and the function should return Bool?

Comment: And now you've totally changed the question, writing `?` where before you had `??`, so now it isn't even clear what the question is about (if it ever was).

Comment: @matt Sorry, I made some edit mistakes. Thank you for pointing out discrepancies. I agree double optionals are very weird. I am not used to working with them. I did not write this function signature and it is used in many places which is why I need to work with this. If you have a better suggestion how to work with my switch statement I am all ears.

Comment: Which Swift/Xcode version are you using? As of Swift 5, `try? getLhs()` returns a simple optional, not a double optional: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0230-flatten-optional-try.md.

Comment: @MartinR I updated my answer -- xCode 10.2.1, unspecified language (4,4.2,5). I changed it to 5 and I am still getting back a Bool?? from the try?. This flattened try would really help me (:

Comment: @Mocha regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262531/way-to-check-for-unused-pods-xcode, it may not have been necessary to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works, but I'm curious why I need to double unwrap the default
>   case? I was thinking once the lhs and rhs get unwrapped from the
>   switch inputs, the default case would work with a Bool? for lhs and
>   rhs.

You aren't changing `lhs` and `rhs` when you do `lhs ?? nil` and `rhs ?? nil`.  You are creating new values.  So when you get to the `default` case, `lhs` and `rhs` are still `Bool??`.  You can use `let lhs` and `let rhs` to capture the unwrapped values as I did in my solution below.

---

Here is another way to do it.  A bit cleaner with some pattern matching:

```
switch (lhs as? Bool, rhs as? Bool) {
case (nil, nil):
    return nil
case (nil, let rhs):
    return rhs
case (let lhs, nil):
    return lhs
case (let lhs?, let rhs?):
    return lhs || rhs
}
```

**Explanation**

Casting the `Bool??` with `as? Bool` leaves you with a `Bool?`.  The `let rhs` and `let lhs` in the pattern matching catch the `Bool?` value so that it can be returned.  In the final `case`, `let lhs?` and `let rhs?` unwrap the `Bool?` values to get `Bool` values so that `||` can be performed.

---

**Test Cases**

```
test(nil, nil) // nil
test(nil, false) // false
test(nil, true) // true
test(nil, Optional(nil)) // nil
test(nil, Optional(false)) // false
test(nil, Optional(true)) // true

test(false, nil) // false
test(false, false) // false
test(false, true) // true
test(false, Optional(nil)) // false
test(false, Optional(false)) // false
test(false, Optional(true)) // true

test(true, nil) // true
test(true, false) // true
test(true, true) // true
test(true, Optional(nil)) // true
test(true, Optional(false)) // true
test(true, Optional(true)) // true

test(Optional(nil), nil) // nil
test(Optional(nil), false) // false
test(Optional(nil), true) // true
test(Optional(nil), Optional(nil)) // nil
test(Optional(nil), Optional(false)) // false
test(Optional(nil), Optional(true)) // true

test(Optional(false), nil) // false
test(Optional(false), false) // false
test(Optional(false), true) // true
test(Optional(false), Optional(nil)) // false
test(Optional(false), Optional(false)) // false
test(Optional(false), Optional(true)) // true

test(Optional(true), nil) // true
test(Optional(true), false) // true
test(Optional(true), true) // true
test(Optional(true), Optional(nil)) // true
test(Optional(true), Optional(false)) // true
test(Optional(true), Optional(true)) // true
```

Comment: This is much cleaner -- Thanks. Can you explain why you needed a let lhs?, let rhs? even though lhs and rhs should already be Bool?

Comment: @Mocha `case let lhs?` in a pattern is like `case let .some(lhs)`. It's bound to value within the optional, rather than the whole optional.

Comment: I didn't know you could use `as T?` to collapse nested optionality like this. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

- `Bool` has 2 values:

  - `true`
  - `false`
- `Bool?` has 3 values, `.none` (a.k.a. `nil`), and one `.some` case wrapping each of the 2 possible cases of `Bool`:

  - `.some(true)`
  - `.some(false)`
  - `.none`
- `Bool??` has 4 values, `.none`, and one `.some` case wrapping each of the 3 possible cases of `Bool?`:

  - `.some(.some(true))`
  - `.some(.some(false))`
  - `.some(.none)`
  - `.none`

To make a first approximation of a solution, we can enumerate all possible values:

```
func getLhs() throws -> Bool? { return nil }
func getRhs() throws -> Bool? { return nil }

func f() -> Bool? {

    let lhs: Bool?? = try? getLhs()
    let rhs: Bool?? = try? getRhs()
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.some(.some(true)), .some(.some(true))): return true
        case (.some(.some(true)), .some(.some(false))): return true
        case (.some(.some(true)), .some(.none)): return true
        case (.some(.some(true)), .none): return true

        case (.some(.some(false)), .some(.some(true))): return true // result of OR
        case (.some(.some(false)), .some(.some(false))): return false
        case (.some(.some(false)), .some(.none)): return false
        case (.some(.some(false)), .none): return false

        case (.some(.none), .some(.some(true))): return true
        case (.some(.none), .some(.some(false))): return false
        case (.some(.none), .some(.none)): return nil
        case (.some(.none), .none): return nil

        case (.none, .some(.some(true))): return true
        case (.none, .some(.some(false))): return false
        case (.none, .some(.none)): return nil
        case (.none, .none): return nil
    }
}
```

So now this is obviously crazy, but we can collapse cases by binding variables:

```
switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.some(r))): return l || r
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.some(r))): return l || r
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.none)): return l
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .none): return l

    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.some(r))): return l || r
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.some(r))): return l || r
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.none)): return l
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .none): return l

    case let (.some(.none), .some(.some(r))): return r
    case let (.some(.none), .some(.some(r))): return r
    case (.some(.none), .some(.none)): return nil
    case (.some(.none), .none): return nil

    case let (.none, .some(.some(r))): return r
    case let (.none, .some(.some(r))): return r
    case (.none, .some(.none)): return nil
    case (.none, .none): return nil
}
```

And we can remove the duplicate cases:

```
switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.some(r))): return l || r
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.none)): return l
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .none): return l

    case let (.some(.none), .some(.some(r))): return r
    case (.some(.none), .some(.none)): return nil
    case (.some(.none), .none): return nil

    case let (.none, .some(.some(r))): return r
    case (.none, .some(.none)): return nil
    case (.none, .none): return nil
}
```

We can then group all the nested `nil` cases:

```
switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.some(r))): return l || r

    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.none)): return l
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .none): return l

    case let (.some(.none), .some(.some(r))): return r
    case let (.none, .some(.some(r))): return r

    case (.some(.none), .some(.none)),
        (.some(.none), .none),
        (.none, .some(.none)),
        (.none, .none):
        return nil
}
```

We can then just catch all those in a `default`:

```
switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.some(r))): return l || r

    case let (.some(.some(l)), .some(.none)): return l
    case let (.some(.some(l)), .none): return l

    case let (.some(.none), .some(.some(r))): return r
    case let (.none, .some(.some(r))): return r

    default: return nil
}
```

## But this whole thing is crazy

Why do you have a function that `throws` AND returns an `Optional`? It would be much better to make the function return a non optional bool, and have the `nil` cases handled by one of the exceptions. Alternatively, you could return a `Result<Bool, Error>`, where one of the error cases encoded the `nil`.

If you had to stick with these types, a `switch` is the wrong way to go about it entirely. You could use `Optional.map` or `Optional.flatMap`, but those would get hairy too.

Comment: Thanks for thorough iteration. I did not create the function that throws and returns an optional. I have to use it because it is very entangled codebase..

Comment: @Mocha No you don't. You could wrap it in a function that 1) return the unwrapped result if it's non-`nil` 2) rethrows the error if an error was thrown 2) throws a different kind of error if the result was `nil`.